# Using href to an id of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use href to take me to a particular div with the id corresponding to what is in the `a href="#1">`.

As an example I have the following three divs.

```html
<ul>
<li id="1" class="cd-single-item cd-active">
    <div class="cd-caption two-third-width">
     <h2>1.</h2>
  <div style="height: 100px">
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
<li id="2" class="cd-single-item cd-not-visible cd-move-right">
 <div class="cd-caption two-third-width">
      <h2>2.</h2>
  <div style="height: 100px">
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
<li id="3" class="cd-single-item cd-not-visible cd-move-right">
 <div class="cd-caption two-third-width">
      <h2>3.</h2>
  <div style="height: 100px">
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

When I have the site in mobile mode, the href's correctly go to the corresponding list item. In normal desktop mode, it doesn't however.

There is a link to the site here. https://what-is-wrong-with-this-css.herokuapp.com/

The links should be coming from the menu icon in the top left hand corner. See how it correctly goes to the list item in mobile but not in desktop. Does anyone know any quick fixes here.

Thanks,

Comment: You need to post enough code, right here, for us to be able to recreate your issue. Please don't expect us to go out to your site and pour over the source code. Also, it's best to not start `id`'s with numbers.

Comment: Hi Scott, thought it would be easiest if I provide an actual example for people to see. Also wouldn't usually start ids with numbers, but this was just for the demo.

Comment: @SwimmingG The Stack Snippet feature allows you to provide the example right here.

Comment: It is best to post examples but you can do that right here in SO and that's best because if your  https://what-is-wrong-with-this-css.herokuapp.com/ link ever becomes broken, this question won't make any sense. Remember, SO isn't just for you to get your question answered, it's a knowledge base for others in the future who may find this question.

Answer (score 4):

It works on mobile because you're scrolling up and down the page. In your desktop version you're using javascript to handle the left/right movement, but not the menu links.

using href to an element ID is for scrolling afaik. If you want to use it for this horizontal set up, you'll need to listen to the window.hashchange event like so:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", funcRef, false);
```

And trigger the scrolling based on the new hashvalue.